# How to individually function Select Tag in .map() method in React?

Tags: reactjs

```js
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('Assigned');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setAge(event.target.value);
        console.log(age)
    };


    return (
        <>
        {
            actionItemArray.map(item => (
                <tr className={styles.styledTable}>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.TITLE}</td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.P_PK}</td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>
                    <Select
                    value={age}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                    <MenuItem value='Assigned'>Assigned</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value='Processing'>Processing</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value='Done'>Done</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                    </td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.START_DATE)}</td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.DUE_DATE)}</td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.owner.FIRST_NAME + item.owner.LAST_NAME}</td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>상세보기</a></td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>수정</a></td>
                    <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag} onClick={openDeleteModal}>삭제</a></td>
                </tr>
            ))
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

Hey guys. This is my code. I'm using a Material-UI Select Form tag but can't figure out how to make this form work individually while I'm using .map() method.

After I render with this code,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siai8.png)

This looks like working fine but the Selects Forms are working at the same time. Need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have one `age` state variable and you are referencing all your `Select` elements to that variable. Of course whenever it changes, all of your elements are getting affected by it. What you need to do is maintain separate variables for every single `Select` element in your list.

So instead of having one static value for age, let's initialise it as an object so that that we can hold value for every list item.

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState({});
```

The idea here is to hold age in this variable against each actionItemArray element. so your state variable should look something like this:

```
age = {
    zz: "Processing",
    aa: "Done",
    cc: "Assigned"
}
```

Of course if you have access to some unique ID, please use that as a key inside this state variable. For now I will be using `item.TITLE` as the key.

This will change the way in which you were setting the state value. Earlier you were directly assigning a string to a single variable, now you will have to update your `handleChange` so that it can target a specific value to save inside your object:

```
const handleChange = (event, title) => {
    setAge({
        ...age,
        title: event.target.value
    };
    console.log(age)
};
```

The next thing that naturally changes is the way you were accessing the state value in your `Select` element. Instead of directly accessing `age`, you will now have to access the specific title inside `age`

```
<Select
    value={age[item.TITLE]}
    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, item.TITLE)}
>
```

This should be enough to get your code up and running. However something else that I suspect you want is to have a default value of "Assigning" when nothing is selected in the `Select` tag. As of now when I initialised the `age` variable, I set it as an empty object `{}`. This would mean that no default value is provided to any Select element, and hence `undefined` will show up as the default value for each element in list. To fix this, you can use an `useEffect` hook to initialise all the values inside this variable as `"Assigning"`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAge(actionItemArray.map(item => age[item.title] ? age[item.title] : "Assigning"))
}, [actionItemArray])
```

Effectively, your final code should look something like this:

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState({});

const handleChange = (event, title) => {
    setAge({
        ...age,
        title: event.target.value
    };
    console.log(age)
};

useEffect(() => {
    setAge(actionItemArray.map(item => age[item.title] ? age[item.title] : "Assigning"))
}, [actionItemArray])

return (
    <>
    {
        actionItemArray.map(item => (
            <tr className={styles.styledTable}>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.TITLE}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.P_PK}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>
                <Select
                    value={age[item.TITLE]}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, item.TITLE)}
                >
                <MenuItem value='Assigned'>Assigned</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value='Processing'>Processing</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value='Done'>Done</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                </td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.START_DATE)}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.DUE_DATE)}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.owner.FIRST_NAME + item.owner.LAST_NAME}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>상세보기</a></td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>수정</a></td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag} onClick={openDeleteModal}>삭제</a></td>
            </tr>
        ))
    }
    </>
)
```

Comment: This one looks more difficult. However, I would love to study this thing too. Thanks PHRYTE!

Comment: Great! Let me know if you find anything difficult to understand, I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index of the item from the map function like this:

```
actionItemArray.map((item,i) => (
            <tr className={styles.styledTable}>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.TITLE}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.P_PK}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>
                <Select
                value={age[i]} // to get the current age value
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,i)}
                >
                <MenuItem value='Assigned'>Assigned</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value='Processing'>Processing</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value='Done'>Done</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                </td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.START_DATE)}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{getUnixTime(item.DUE_DATE)}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}>{item.owner.FIRST_NAME + item.owner.LAST_NAME}</td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>상세보기</a></td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag}>수정</a></td>
                <td className={styles.styledTd}><a className={styles.styledATag} onClick={openDeleteModal}>삭제</a></td>
            </tr>
```

In the `handleChange` function you use that index to change the value of that particular item only and you need to set the initial value of `age` to an empty array like this:

```
 const [age,setAge] = React.useState([]);
 const handleChange = (event,index) => {
    setAge([...age.map((data,i) => i === index ? event.target.value:data )]);
    
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this one.

Comment: Sure! let me know if it did not work.